# Trying to load stylesheet only for touch devices with Modernizr

Tags: javascript, css, modernizr

I've heard that Modernizr's test for touch is one of the best ways to test if the device a page is being viewed on is touch or multi-touch enabled.

I'm trying to use it ( the touch test ) as well as modernizr's load function to load a stylesheet only when the device has touch capability.

However, my code doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Modernizr.load({
    test: Modernizr.touch,
    yep: 'assets/css/touch.css'
});
</script>
```

Update: Sorry, I should have clarified what not-working means:
When I visit the page on my multi-touch smart-phone, the styles are not taking effect.
I applied the styles in the normal stylesheet and they take effect, but when I switch them into touch.css and try to load that conditionally with Modernizr, it doesn't work.
My copy of Modernizr does include yepnope and the touch test as I am using both in other instances where they are working.

Comment: What does _"doesn't seem to be working"_ mean? Are you getting errors in the console? Does your build of __Modernizr__ include __yepnope__?

Comment: @Mathletics I updated the question with answers to your questions.

Answer (score 3):

Your script block looks correct, so the problem must be something else. Since you are certain your Modernzr build includes Yepnope, here are a few guesses:

1. Your script block comes before the script tag including Modernzr
2. The path to the CSS is wrong

I would start by adding a `callback: function(){ alert('loaded!'); }` to the .load() statement to see if that happens. If not, I would replace `Modernzr.touch` with `true` and test on a desktop browser instead to see if there are and Javascript errors happening.

Comment: Good suggestions, another test may be to put the CSS in 'nope' just to check if it will be loaded in other situations?

Comment: Yeah, that would also rule out the possibility that the current test fails on that device for some reason.

Comment: Interesting question though, based on the information in the question, OP *does* know what he is doing. Not behind a computer at the moment, so unable to test myself. Interested in the outcome :)

Comment: @thaJeztah Thank you for your suggestions. I tried them and they assured that the path to the css file was correct. I ended up downloading a new copy of modernizr and now it works.

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg Thank you for your suggestions. I tried them and it loaded when true. I ended up downloading a new copy of Modernizr and now it works. That was weird.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working! Good luck on your project. I may have to flag this question as 'too localised' - not meant to be rude!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be not to load an extra stylesheet for touch enabled devices, but to add a class to the `<body>` instead.

Like so:

```
if(Modernizr.touch) {
    $('body').addClass('touch');
}
```

And then prefix your stylesheet classes with `.touch`:

```
a:hover {
    color: red;
}


a, .touch a:hover {
    color: blue;
}
```

Loading an extra stylesheet is a good idea when there are many and substantial differences in the CSS for touch and non touch devices. In that case using only one stylesheet is not a good idea since it will become quite big in size. If you only have minor differences, adding a .touch class to the body (or any other element) is the better way to go, I think.